# How to install kitchen shelves in a wall which conceals a pocket door?

Tags: mounting, shelving, pocket-door

What are methods to install kitchen shelves on a wall behind which is the cavity for a pocket door? There are a few studs in the cavity but I'm not sure if they are thin studs and if they would be appropriate to support the weight of kitchen shelves. I would need to make sure to use short screws which wouldn't penetrate so deep as to collide with the concealed door.

Answer (score 2):

Cut and install a plywood sheet to cover the entire space. Mark or measure the locations of the vertical wood strips (studs). Use screws just long enough to go past the drywall about 3/4" into the strips. Sand and paint the plywood, then attach shelves wherever you need.

Comment: Yes, and to make it clear to the OP: to bear the load make sure the bottom plywood edge rests firmly on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Use freestanding self-supporting shelves. They are very common in commercial kitchens, and work just as well in home kitchens.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in a kitchen - to add a pocket door from mudroom to kitchen.

If you want to do this right you need to bolt the shelves from the door side.   I am not sure if your door is fully installed or not yet but you will need to take off the face of the pocket area.   You do not need to do anything to the functional pocket door so it is drywall work, not a major repair.

Take the drywall off - drill holes from the other side where you want them and you will be bolting them from the door side and nut will go on to the shelving side.   I would add a lock washer to that side so that you can tighten the bolt without having to be there later on.

I would also add some supports beyond drywall if you aren't hitting a stud - 1x4 or whatever.   There are other things you can do or use but I wouldn't suggest those for kitchen shelves.   Even if you don't plan on plates being on them, someone else could.

Answer (score -1):

Get some prong nuts:
[image]

it should be possible to use them to bolt the shelf to the 1x4 timbers that comprise pocket frame. you'll need to remove the door first. drill from the kitchen side to get the right position for attaching the brackets. A piece of threaded rod on a string may help.